# Virtualenv keeps being built by python 2 rather than python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I keep getting the below error when trying to create a virtual environment for python.  It seems to me that virtualenv/pip is defaulting to using python 2 rather than when building the environment.  **Not** that that environment is being *made **for*** python2 but it is being *made **by*** python2.  I think that is the problem, any help is appreciated.

```
[brad@reason Attack_Analysis]$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.7 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.7
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
New python executable in /home/brad/Development/Attack_Analysis/venv/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /home/brad/Development/Attack_Analysis/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...

  Complete output from command /home/brad/Developme...s/venv/bin/python3.7 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/utils/glibc.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py)
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2438, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 768, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1030, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 983, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "/home/brad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 861, in call_subprocess
    raise OSError("Command {} failed with error code {}".format(cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/brad/Developme...s/venv/bin/python3.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

My vitualenv is up to date

```
[brad@reason Attack_Analysis]$ virtualenv --version
16.2.0
```

My pip is updated but it seems to be for python 2, not 3.  How do I get it to work for python 3?  I installed via make install as I'm on redhat 7.5.

```
[brad@reason Attack_Analysis]$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

When using pip3, it seems to find it without root, but not with, so my pip3 is out of date.  Not sure how to update it when I need root to do it and have this problem.

```
[brad@reason ~]$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
[brad@reason ~]$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
[sudo] password for brad: 
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

My PYTHONPATH is empty.  Should it be?  I don't think I changed this before, not sure if this is an issue.

```
[brad@reason ~]$ echo $PYTHONPATH

[brad@reason ~]$
```

Comment: not sure about the errors, but you could try pip3 instead of pip

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: "[brad@reason ~]$ echo $PYTHONPATH" return an empty line, I assume this is wrong, what should it be?

Comment: On a side-note, I would recommend using `pipenv` instead of `virtualenv`. This is the de facto standard nowadays. Python.org itself uses `pipenv` in their guide for managing application dependencies: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/

Comment: I ended up using pipenv and I was able to get everything working.  I feel like I should be able to use virtualenv as I kind of prefer it.  I don't like where pipenv puts my environment files and I like how virtualenv clearly shows me I'm in the environment in my prompt.  Regardless, pipenv did work and that is the most important thing.  Thanks for your help @JChris.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this problem (on Linux):

```
apt install python3-pip
pip3 install virtualenv
```